# Can't create an img element based on a Blob

Tags: html, typescript, blob

I am trying to create a img element based on an image that I am getting as an ArrayBuffer(which I then convert to a Blob). Here is what I've tried so far

```
private onProfilePictureChanged = (event: any) => {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e: any) => {
                this.setState({
                    profilePicture: new Blob([e.target.response], {
                        type: "image/jpeg"
                    }),
                    profilePictureURL: URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([e.target.response], {
                        type: "image/jpeg"
                    }))
                }, () => console.log(this.state))
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

The image takes it's `src` from the state. After converting the ArrayBufer to Blob then to URL I am getting this url `blob:file:///00756259-cff1-4459-9b05-fe8cfbc1b361`  . But the image isn't displayed, only it's `alt`. I also get no error in the console, so I am not sure what the problem might be.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], { type: 'image/jpeg' }) you can try this

Comment: I am getting this error: Argument of type 'Uint8Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BlobPart[]'.
  Type 'Uint8Array' is missing the following properties from type 'BlobPart[]': pop, push, concat, shift, and 3 more.